# Get the record (row) in a table with the most recent (greatest date) LINQ to SQL C#

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table called tblTrans it has 4 fields:
ID, CustID, TDATE, Name

How can in in LINQ to SQL CE, get the newest or most recent row.  I want the query to return all the fields for this row.
I was trying this and could not get it to work:

tblTrans retTrans =
  (from c by c.TDATE into g orderby c.TDATE)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var retTrans = (
        from c in tblTrans
        orderby c.TDATE descending
        select c
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: one more question.  Instead for returning the whole row, how about just returning the field "TDATE"

Comment: @Tony - Change the select to `select c.TDATE`. You could also do `tblTrans.Max(c => c.TDATE)`. (Don't forget to accept my answer. ;-))